# How to add an adview to a layout that is shared in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, admob

I have a layout that I use in multiple activities.
I want to show an adMob adView in all of them.
If I get it right, I need an ID for each activity.
I'm trying to change the adUnitId from code in each activity onCreate but it says that the adUnitId needs to be set before load.

My layout adView:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/view_album_banner_ad_unit_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        >
```

My code:

```
_adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
_adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.view_album_banner_ad_unit_id));


_adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior. I implemented some lazy loading view for that, however that is too much overhead. Just add your ads by code. If you have issues to insert at to the right position use the [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) class. You can [change the desired adview containing layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#setLayoutResource%28int%29) while inflating it.

Comment: I added it from the code but now I cannot locate it correctly. How can viewStub help?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably little need to use a different adUnitId in each of the different Activities. If there are all in the same app I wouldn't worry about it.

But if this is library code and the Activities are in different apps then just change the adUnitId  via the String variable.